# Prove: $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{j} \geq 1 + \frac{n}{2}$ for all positive integers $n$.

Tags: summation, harmonic-functions

Given the following proof.

*Proof*: by induction on n

*Base Case*: $n = 1$ is trivial. Done

*Inductive Step*: suppose for $n \geq 1$ we have  $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{2^n}\frac{1}{j} \geq 1 + \frac{n}{2}$. We show for $n + 1$. Observe
$$
\begin{equation} \begin{split}
(1)& \quad\sum_{j=1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{1}{j} &= \sum_{j=1}^{2^n} \frac{1}{j} + \sum_{j=2^n + 1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{1}{j} \\ 
(2)&&\geq 1 + \frac{n}{2} + \left(2^{n+1} - 2^n\right)\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \\
&&= 1 + \frac{n}{2} + 1 - \frac{1}{2} \\
&&= 1 + \frac{n+1}{2}
\end{split} \end{equation}
$$
Done.

Two questions: How does the procedure of separating the summation of the LHS in (1) to the two summands on the RHS in (1) work? In addition, how does one evaluate $\sum\limits_{j=2^n + 1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac{1}{j}$ to be the third summand in (2)?

NOTE: The summations limits in second summand of the RHS of (1) may be wrong. I could not remember fully, what it was.

In addition, I am NOT asking why we separate in (1) to prove. I am asking how the algebraic manipulations works in going from LHS of (1) to RHS of (1).

Comment: The separation allows you to use the inductive hypothesis (the value for $n$ when proving for $n{+}1$). The evaluation there is to an inequality (lower limit).

Comment: @Joffan I understand the $\textit{why}$ we separate. In this question, I am asking particularly, how the LHS of (1) goes to the RHS of (1). And then my 2nd question as prefaced above :)

Comment: As the number of summations is finite, you can break the summation from any point you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: Notice:  $\sum_{k=1}^{M} a_k= a_1 + a_2 + ........   + a_{M-1}+a_M =$

$\underbrace{a_1 + a_2 + ...+ a_W} + \underbrace{a_{W+1}+.....   + a_{M-1}+a_M}=$

$\sum_{k=1}^{W} a_k + \sum_{k=W+1}^{M} a_k$.

We can split any sum anywhere that way.

Second question:

If $2^{n}+1 \le j \le 2^{n+1}$ then

$\frac 1{2^{n} + 1} \ge \frac 1j \ge \frac 1{2^{n+1}}$ so

$\frac 1j \ge \frac 1{2^{n+1}}$

SO $\sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac 1j \ge \sum_{j=2^n+1}^{2^{n+1}} \frac 1{2^{n+1}}=$

$\underbrace{\frac 1{2^{n+1}}+\frac 1{2^{n+1}}+\frac 1{2^{n+1}}+ .... + \frac 1{2^{n+1}}}_{(2^{n+1} - 2^n)\text{ times}}=$

$(2^{n+1} - 2^n)\frac 1{2^{n+1}}=$

$\frac {2^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}} - \frac {2^{n}}{2^{n+1}} = 1-\frac 12 = \frac 12$.

Comment: Thank you @fleabood! Question: When you evaluated $\sum_{j=2^n + 1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, where did the " + 1 " part go in the lower bound of the summation when you find the summand to add $(2^{n+1} - 2^n)$ times?

Comment: Nvm, I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the number of summations is finite, you can break the summation from any point you desire. Hence, it is straightforward to reach RHS (1) from LHS (1).

For the second part of your question it is easy to replace $\frac{1}{j}$ with minimum value in the range of summation $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. Therefore,

$$\sum_{j = 2^n + 1}^{2^{n+1}}\frac{1}{j} > \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{j = 2^n + 1}^{2^{n+1}}1 = (2^{n+1} - (2^n + 1) + 1)\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} = (2^{n+1} - 2^n)\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$$.